# "She pulled me up from that hole" - "She pulled me out of that hole" Differences?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In this context: "**I was walking through the jungle, when I fell into a dark hole, when I fell in, I looked up and saw a girl reaching her hands out for me, She grabbed my hands and pulled me up from that hole".**

Would it sound right? And it so, what's the difference between: 
**She pulled me up from that hole,**
**She pulled me out of that hole,**
**She pulled me from that hole**

Considering that a hole is a *deep caved place*, and if someone wants to take me out of there, they would have to bring me *UP*, since they would be above me and I would be under them. 
Would it still be acceptable to use "pulled up from"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the orientation of the hole, there may be no difference.

If you are "*in* a hole", you will always be pulled "*out*" in order to exit, whether the "hole" is physical or psychological.

> My mind was stuck *in* a deep, dark hole, and my counselor helped pull me *out* of it.
>   I fell *in* a hole in the ground and my friends helped pull me *out*.

If the hole is considered *under* you, then when you are rescued, you will be pulled *up*.

> I fell *down* into a sinkhole and the fire department pulled me *up*.
>   I had fallen into a bottomless pit of depression, and finally pulled myself *up*.

Comment: As you are here, let me ask you one more question:

Let's suppose I got stuck on the roof (don't ask me how, let's just say I glued myself on the roof), and someone walked under me, looked up at  me and I said: Help me!
What would the guy do? Would he Pull me DOWN? Does this sound correct? Considering that I was stuck above him and he was under me, he would have to pull me down in order to take me off the roof.

Comment: @DavydDiniz That would depend. If he is on a ladder, below you, he would "Pull you **down** from the roof". If instead, the only way was to climb **onto** the roof to reach you, he would "pull you **off** the roof", neither "up" nor "down" since he is on the same level as you might be.  In both situations ultimately "He got you **down** from the roof", once you are standing on the ground.  If you were glued on your back to the roof top, he would "Pull you **up** off the roof", to separate you from the roof, then bring you "**down** from the roof". "He got you off the roof" implies **down**.

Comment: So If I was 3 meters above him, but he was still able to reach me with his hands, would he pull me down from the roof, or pull me off?